# Pandigital Supernova tv audio problem

Tags: audio, pandigital-supernova

I was wondering if anyone has had sucess in getting audio through Mitsubishi 1080 DTV speaker when connecting tablet to tv.  I am using a SIIG  Hdmi to VGA converter with audio.  The video comes through great but when I connect the red and white audio cables the sound comes through for about 2 seconds then nothing.  If anyone has had sucess doing this please tell me what you equipment was used to accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried playing audio from any other device via the same input? This way you could verify that it's not a problem in the TV. It could also help to test the tablet with another TV.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  You want believe this it was the power cord on the converter causing the problem.  I don't know why but when I unplugged it the sound came through prefect.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem was solved. You may want to answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted as soon as it's available :)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>[OP solved the problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38056/#comment-51426):</sup>

> it was the power cord on the converter causing the problem. I don't know why but when I unplugged it the sound came through prefect.